# Using javascript instead of opal in Hyperstack

Tags: javascript, ruby, reactjs, hyperstack

All of the documentation for Hyperstack revolves around using Hyperstack with Opal.

Is it possible to use Hyperstack's isomorphic models with javascript, instead of Opal?

Comment: It's for ruby. Opal just converts to JS. I would do an initial conversion, then see what the opal outputs. that will give you an idea of what you can do.

Comment: So you want to write your FE code in JS, but have some reasonable mapping to your Rails models?

So you would say Todo.title() in JS instead of Todo.title in ruby for example?

and Todo.each(function(todo) { ... }) in JS?

well I don't think it would be too hard to make that work.

Comment: @MitchVanDuyn Right. For those already comfortable with javascript, they could leverage hyperstack's features without learning the component DSL

Comment: okay well this conversation is probably better on our slack channel.  Join here https://join.slack.com/t/hyperstack-org/shared_invite/enQtNTg4NTI5NzQyNTYyLTYzYTZhYTE2MGE5ZTQ0OTAyNDVlMzE5OTk5NWNmZmMzYjhkZGY1MDc3MGFjMGZlYzE5ZWJhZDJiMmQyYzAxMjY